# independent vs. uncorrelated

Tags: stochastic-processes, partial-differential-equations

If I have two stochastic processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$ that are dependent however $dX_tdY_t=0$
where $dX_t=a(z,x,t)dt$ and $dY_t=b(z,x,t)dt$ and $dZ_t=dW_t$(Brownian motion) then from Ito formula $du(Xt,Yt,Zt)=u_tdt+u_XdX+u_Ydt+u_ZdZ+0.5u_{ZZ}dZdZ$, which is an SDE and if I want to solve it for all terms of dt be zero: it implies I have a pde: $u_t+a*u_x+b*u_y+u_z=0$.
Here is the question: this pde in three space variables which is to be solved assumes x,z and y are independent but it came from considering dependent variables. Where is the paradox? So when we write a pde which follows from Ito we care only about the fact that they are uncorrelated? Because I don't see any dependence embedded into the pde...Please clarify that for me.

Comment: @ Medan : first observe that in your case $u_t=0$, as long as $u$ doesn't depend explicitely on time as a function. Second I'm not sure about what you mean when you say that this pde is to be solved assuming that $x,y$ and $z$ are independent, could you clarify this further ? Maybe you are mixing two distinct notions, first independence in variables in differential calculus context, second independence in the probabilistic context. Best regards.

Comment: I meant my function u(t,x,y,z), sorry about it. And yes, this is exactly my question: from the class in PDE I have learned that x,y,z have no randomness and they are independent. that is for each x,y,z fixed the function should satisfy a pde. But I am trying to get a connection with probabilistic context. and if they were independent in probability then everything is fine, but what if not?

Comment: @ Medan : Independent in the "pde context" means IMO that you can express $u$ as an explicit function of $x,y,z$ not that $X_t,Y_t,Z_t$ are independent in probability. Regarding the fact that your "not random" pde is originating from a probabilistic context, it only expresses the structure that you need for $u$ seen as a stochastic process to be a (local) martingale nothing else nothing more. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge: I understand what you are saying but let me pose another question: say, my PDE comes from writing Ito formula and setting terms with dt to 0 where X_t and Y_t are dependent processes. So I get something like u_t+u_x+u_y=0. Now I treat x and y as independent in differential calculus context and solve numerically. On the other hand by Feymnann Kac I can compute an expectation which will take into account all probabilistic structure. Thus my question is, are they the same?

Comment: @ Medan : Your condition is here to guarantee that $u$ is a martingale, so that $u_0=u(0,x,y,z)=E[u(T,X_T,Y_T,Z_T)|t=0,X_0=x,Y_0=y,Z_0=z]$ so depending on your problem exact setting you might solve the "martingale condition" pde to get $u_0$ or use any other "lead" that can help you determine deterministacally $u_0$. If you are a probabilist used to Monte Carlo Simulations you might prefer simulating $X_T,Y_T,Z_T$ and use LLN or CLT to get a value (unless you can calculate analytically this integral). This is generally a matter of taste. Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge: I understand what you wrote. However, you have not mentioned whether $X_T,Y_T,Z_T$ are dependent or correlated, thus the equality should hold in either case, right? I mean $u(0,x,y,z)=\Ex_0[u(T,X_T,Y_T,Z_T)]$ is always true. Thus if I want to find this quantity RHS can be done by MonteCarlo or LHS by Finite difference for the pde u(0,x,y,z) satisfies, and one of those gives me an answer, correct?

Comment: @ Medan : As far as I know yes.